# I have a series of data, and with the data i want to add two rows to go with each row of data that i already have

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am currently using pandas to go through the data, I haven't been able to find any code that adds a row to previous data.

My current code:

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import datetime
from dataclasses import dataclass
from openpyxl.styles import Font,Color,Alignment,Border,Side,colors
import numpy as np
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell
import xlwt
from xlwt import Workbook

root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300, bg = 'lightsteelblue')
canvas1.pack()

def getExcel():
    global df

    import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    df = pd.read_excel (import_file_path)
    del df['PART CODE']
    del df['SUPPLIER CODE']
    del df['COMPANY OR SUB-CONT']
    del df['SUB-CONT UNIT COST']
    del df['HLR']
    del df['HOURLY MULTIPLIER']
    del df['MATERIAL MULTIPLIER']
    del df ['ROUGH-IN HOURS']
    del df['FINISH HOURS']
    del df['PRELIMINARY TEXT']
    del df['FORMAL TEXT']
    del df['SUBCONT TEXT']
    del df['Part Image Path']
    df.insert(0,'Id','')


    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', df.shape[0]+1)

browseButton_Excel = tk.Button(text='Select Excel File', command=getExcel, bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=browseButton_Excel)

root.mainloop()
```

The data that I currently have comes out as

row1  1  1  1
row2  2  2  2
row3  3  3  3

I want to have the output be

row1  1  1  1
row2
row3
row4  2  2  2
row5
row6
row7  3  3  3
row8
row9

In that new output I added two rows that I could put new data when I am done with my code. Any thoughts?

Comment: I was able to find this code
    df1 = pd.DataFrame([[''] * len(df.columns)], columns=df.columns)
    df = df1.append(df, ignore_index=True)
this let me insert a row, but it put it at the top of my data, and i want to put 2 rows for each data row i already have, my current sheet is 13000 lines long, would take forever.

Comment: hi @JcodeL, what exactly do u want to achieve? kindly reformat ur code and explain what u want